# If $x^{2}-x\in Z(R)$ for all $x\in R$, then $R$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $x^{2}-x\in Z(R)$ for all $x\in R$, then $R$ is commutative.

I need to proof this theorem and I have something like this below. However, I do not know how to continue this proof.

$(x+y)^{2}-(x+y)=x^{2}+xy+yx+y^{2}-x-y=(x^{2}-x)+(y^{2}-y)+xy+yx\in Z(R)$

so $xy+yx\in Z(R)$

Answer (score 13):

You’re on the right track. From $xy+yx\in Z(R)$ we get $x(xy+yx)=(xy+yx)x$, or, after expanding, $x^2y+xyx=xyx+yx^2$, and hence $x^2y=yx^2$. This shows that every square is in $Z(R)$. Can you see how to finish it from there?

Comment: @ Brain M. Scott: I understood what you wrote but I can't really see how to finish this.

Comment: @Monika: Look at $x^2-(x^2-x)$. Does that help?

Comment: @ Brain M. Scott: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @Monika: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is Theorem 2 in the paper

http://archive.maths.nuim.ie/staff/sbuckley/Papers/bm_variations.pdf