# Prove that the following ring is commutative

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $(R, +, ·)$ be a ring and $x^2-x ∈ Z(R)$ for any $x ∈ R$. Prove that the ring is commutative.
Here is my attempt:

$x^2-x ∈ Z(R)$ then for any $y ∈ R$:
$$(x^2-x)y=y(x^2-x)$$
$$x^2y-xy=yx^2-yx$$
$$x^2y-xy=x^2y-yx$$ (Pretty sure I can't change those elements like that, but I can't think of anything else)
$$-xy=-yx$$
$$xy=yx$$
which means the ring is commutative.

What is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\forall x \in R, x^2-x \in Z(G)$, than $R$ is commutative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906866/if-forall-x-in-r-x2-x-in-zg-than-r-is-commutative) and [Another link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454715/if-x2-x-in-zr-for-all-x-in-r-then-r-is-commutative) and [Another link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2947554/let-a-be-a-ring-and-za-its-center-show-that-if-x2-x-in-za-for-ever?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Another Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221409/prove-that-r-is-commutative?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: and [Another Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2219307/proving-commutative-ring-with-conditions?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Another Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416646/commutative-rings-exercise?noredirect=1&lq=1)